# How to make a secure commnication between two applications?

Tags: security

I need to do a communication between two applications, and I want to ensure the client application identity.

I wanna know if is there some pattern to make something like this:

- The client application has a key and secret
- The client send some info to the main application with identity data
- The main application verify the client and returns the requested data

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - your question is not in a format where it can be answered succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to investigate client and server TLS certificates. They will allow for a mutual authentication between the server and the client.

Answer (score -2):

I think You are talking about server-client communication. In this case, you have to search RESTful API. With REST, you implement endpoint which returns your data as a JSON. So you can use the data in Desktop app,Mobile app or Web app and with this way you can resolve the security risk. Because in mobile app
or desktop app, conneting to db is risky. You cant put your db options in your app. Implement a REST which returns JSON and send a http request in client.
If response is OK. Parse the JSON and use in the client

Here is the simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913147/return-json-data-with-php) in php

Comment: REST has nothing to do with security.